# Подскажите как заставить код Python выполнять другой скрипт из другого файла?

Tags: python

Есть 2 файла с кодом, нужно научить бота запускать второй при определенной команде, при импорте этот код выполняется сразу, без команды, но нужно сделать так, чтобы он выполнялся при написании команды. Как такое осуществить? Python 3.9 пишу в Pycharm[image: import]

Comment: Вы заметили, что на конце `import telebot` нет никаких **.py**, а в другой строке есть, и PyCharm подчёркивает красным, явно намекая, что что-то не так?

Comment: Ещё почитайте про `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0):

Салам. Вариант 1) import os os.system("echo.py")
Это не лучший вариант другой вариант это в папку с проектом закинуть свой скрипт echo.py
И в основном файле сделать импорт своего файла (без .py) разбить echo.py на функции и вызывать через команду echo.funk()